# Error: could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'struct'

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, g++, constexpr

```
template <typename T, unsigned int S>
class Vec
{
T data[S];

public:
    constexpr Vec(const T& s)
        : data{s} {}
};

template <typename T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Cols>
class Mat
{
    Vec<T, Cols> data[Rows];

public:
    constexpr Mat(const T& s)
        : data{Vec<T, Cols>(s)} {}
};

int main()
{
    constexpr Mat<double, 2, 2> m{1.0};
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
source/main.cpp:24:25: error: could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Vec<double, 2>'
   : data{Vec<T, Cols>(s)} {}
                         ^
```

Can anybody tell me what this error mean, and how can I fix it? I have never encountered this error before. I'm using GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 8.2.1 and `g++ -std=c++17 -O3` as arguments.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::array`? Also, I think your `Vec` constructor is a bit wrong. Do you really want to pass only one value to array?

Comment: Using `std::array` instead of `Vec` class? Because `Vec` has more functions to do some operations, like adding and subtracting two vectors. And yes, I want to initialize the whole array with the same value.

Comment: You can also wrap `std::array`

Comment: @DavidBermejo Except that's not what `arr{value}` does when `arr` is a raw array type. It initializes only the first element of the array with `value`, and the rest are default-initialized.

Comment: @aschepler Oh I was wrong I though just that, sorry.

Comment: To initialize all members of an array (either raw or `std::array`) with the same value, you would need a "trick" something like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33be3f42e8fcb4ac

Comment: @aschepler That is super useful, thank you! I've come up with a solution using your proposal.

Answer (score 2):

Rows is 2. So the size of

```
Vec<T, Cols> data[Rows];
```

data is 2. But `data` array is initialized only by one item:

```
: data{Vec<T, Cols>(s)} {} 
       // initializer has only one element
```

because you provided user-defined constructor by

```
constexpr Vec(const T& s)
        : data{s} {}
```

the default constructor of `Vec` is deleted, and the second item in `data` cannot be constructed.
Add default ctor:

```
constexpr Vec()
    :data {} {}
```

Comment: I thought that initializing an array in a constructor with a single item initializes all elements to that given item. Do I need to create a tuple to achieve that?

Comment: The simplest solution is to use vector which has constructor taking value and the number of created elements.

Comment: You know that this `data{s}` initialize only first item with `s` value, and the second has default value 0.0 ?

Comment: No, I didn't know that, I thought that the whole array would be initialized to that value. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1):

The problem that I had was supposing that using array initialization with a single element initializes the whole array instead of only the first element.

As @aschepler suggested, using integer sequences fixes the compiler error:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, unsigned int S>
class Vec
{
    std::array<T, S> data;

public:
    constexpr Vec(const T& s)
        : Vec(s, std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned int, S>{}) {}

private:
    template <unsigned int... Seq>
    constexpr Vec(const T& s, std::integer_sequence<unsigned int, Seq...>)
        : data{(static_cast<void>(Seq), s)...} {}
};

template <typename T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Cols>
class Mat
{
    std::array<Vec<T, Cols>, Rows> data;

public:
    constexpr Mat(const T& s)
        : Mat(s, std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned int, Rows>{}) {}

private:
    template <unsigned int... Seq>
    constexpr Mat(const T& s, std::integer_sequence<unsigned int, Seq...>)
        : data{(static_cast<void>(Seq), Vec<T, Cols>(s))...} {}
};
```